# crypt() not returning standard MD5 Hash?

Tags: c, unix, hash, crypt

I'm trying to use the `crypt()` function found in `<crypt.h>` in C, and when I attempt to hash a string in MD5 for example, it returns something different than a standard MD5 hash would produce from a tool such as `md5sum`. Example/Proof:

`hash.c:`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crypt.h>

#define MD5 "$1$"

int main() {

        const char string[] = "helloworld";
        char * hash = crypt(string, MD5);

        printf("%s\n",hash);

        return 0;
}
```

I compile with `gcc -o hash hash.c -lcrypt` and run:

```sh
./hash
$1$$edK86ZB1Vvaz2eneY.itb.
```

From my knowledge of UNIX systems, the format of the output of crypt matches the password format of UNIX users whereas the first part is the hash ID/type, the second part is the salt and the third is the actual hash - `$id$salt$hash`. Yet the ACTUAL standard MD5 hash of `helloworld` is `fc5e038d38a57032085441e7fe7010b0`. Is there any way to produce this hash using `crypt()`? Many thanks!

Comment: Who told you crypt was MD5?

Comment: First of all, the algorithm used by [`crypt`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/crypt.html) is *implementation defined*, so there's no requirement to use MD5 or any other algorithm. Secondly, MD5 is old and obsolete since many years. Modern variants use DES or one of the SHA variants.

Comment: I thought the second argument of `crypt()` defined the hash type it returned. `$1$` being MD5 with an empty salt which i pass in

Comment: OP is presumably using glibc, whose `crypt(3)` implementation allows you to specify an alternative algorithm.

Comment: @Shawn yes I am using glibc

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I realise MD5 is old an obsolete however Im not using it for anything to do with keeping information or storing data. Its purely for educational reasons

Comment: Assuming Linux, then [the Linux `crypt` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) should be more relevant. It states that the resulting length of an MD5 "encrypted" password is fixed as 22 characters. That means you can't use a plain hex-encoded string.

Comment: The mistake you're making is in thinking the encrypted password is just the plain base16 encoded hash of it plus the salt. That's obviously not what's being returned.

Comment: @Shawn That makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string returned by the glibc implementation of `crypt()` is not just a simple hash of the salt + password encoded into base 16.

If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/crypt/md5-crypt.c) of the MD5 version, you'll see among other things a loop that takes a previous MD5 hash and hashes that, for one thousand repetitions. Then it's turned into a string with repeated use of a function named `__b64_from_24bit()` that encodes 3 bytes of the final MD5 hash at a time (not in linear order) into what I assume is base 64.

This is why what you see looks nothing like the output of `md5sum` or the like.